# Browsing two different revisions of the same repository

Tags: git, version-control, diff

Say that I have a rather large repository, and I want to compare two specific revisions. But don't just want to just see the diff, I want to be able to browse through the code, jump between files etc.

An example might be opening up Rails 2.3 and 3 at the same time and looking at different implementation of the same thing.

The way I do this now is just a **local clone, checkout a different version in each, open them both in my editor (SublimeText) and browse.**

Is there any better way to do this? Are there any tools that make this easier?

Comment: None that I'd know of (except local clones). +1 for a really interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only **one** [working directory](http://progit.org/book/ch1-3.html#the_three_states), and you want to put two revisions there? Not going to work.

It possible to setup a simple web-based server to explore the repository, and then you could open two browser tabs/windows and inspect the code at different revisions. Instructions on how to setup GitWEB are [here](http://progit.org/book/ch4-6.html). git.kernel.org uses this, so to have get a feeling on how it looks like you can open any of the repos http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=summary.

Answer (score 1):

You can open two terminal windows and view a file from specific revision.

Say, you have repo rails.

In first terminal you type:

```
~/rails/ $ git show v2.3.14:Rakefile
```

And in the second:

```
~/rails/ $ git show v3.2.0:Rakefile
```

Where v2.3.14 and v3.2.0 are tags for specific versions you are interested  in, and the "Rakefile" is a file you want to see.